# Retrieve password using rest framework JWT

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to use Django JWT rest framework to create a password recovery link?

An example would be to recover password by email and create an access token for it.

Or do I need to use the features of Django admin to do this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

This is not something you can do in Django JWT REST framework alone. You need to write custom views to fulfil this behavior.

You can subclass `auth.PasswordResetView` and create a new JWT token manually that is used in a password reset link delivered to email address of *active* user.

The following example is given in [`django-rest-framework-jwt`](https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#creating-a-new-token-manually) for creating JWT token manually.

```
# Source: https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#creating-a-new-token-manually
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings

jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER

payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)
token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
```

You'll also need to subclass `auth.PasswordResetConfirmView` to verify that the token wasn't used/expired.

Comment: Your link is showing 404 error please update it sir, Thank You

Comment: Thanks @NikhilBhardwaj for making me aware of this. The project was move to a different repository. Hence the broken link.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [Djoser](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#djoser). 
This library would allow you to configure a password reset endpoint, user creation, password change, configure the email, etc. It is also compatible with JWT.